# Get values from 2 json files with condition in React

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, if-statement

I have 2 json files statesCode.json and cityAndzipCode.json having following structure

statesCode.json

```
{ "Alabama" : "AB" ,
 "Alaska" : "AS" ,
 }
```

cityAndzipCode.json

```
{ "Alabama" : { city : "Birmingham" , zipcode : "123456" },
 "Alaska" : { city : "Anchorage" , zipcode : "453567" }, 
---
 }
```

now in my component I  am returning stateAbbreviation , cityName and zipCode .
I have to write a condition that if we get only stateAbbreviation in url and cityName and zipCode are null, then we have to check the list in cityAndzipCode.json and return
city and zipCode as array .

I was able to apply this logic, kindly tell me what am I doing wrong

```
if ( url . zipCode === null && url.cityName === null && url . stateAbbreviation )
 { 
 if ( url . stateAbbreviation === stateCodes ) {
 url . cityName = stateCodes ;
 url . zipCode = stateCodes [ 1 ];
 }
```

Comment: how are you importing these JSONs? show us the declarations of `stateCodes` and `url`.

Comment: What is info.cityName ?

Comment: importing stateCodes like this
 const stateCodes = require ( '../../sections/util/stateCodes.json' );

url is a constant which has all cityName, stateAbbreviations, stateCodes,zipCode, it returns them in array format

Comment: @Rupam Can you please console.log the url, stateCodes, and cityAndzipCode here in question.

Comment: I wull do that , but my problem is , I have to compare the stateAbbreviation from first json file, compare that corresponding stateName to the second json file, and return the values from that entry

Comment: here's what the console looks like
`
{
cityName:null,
zipCode:null,
stateAbbreviation:'AB',
}
`
@SurjeetBhadauriya

Comment: @RameshReddy provided in the comments

Comment: @Rupam Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am beginning with a hope that your data looks like as below:

```
stateCodes = { 
  "Alabama": "AB" ,
  "Alaska": "AS" ,
};
      
cityAndzipCode = { 
  "Alabama": { city : "Birmingham" , zipcode : "123456" },
  "Alaska": { city : "Anchorage" , zipcode : "453567" }, 
 };

url = { cityName:null, zipCode:null, stateAbbreviation:'AB' };

if (!url.zipCode && !url.cityName && url.stateAbbreviation) { 
  const index = Object.values(stateCodes).indexOf(url.stateAbbreviation);  
  const value = Object.keys(stateCodes)[index];
  if (value) {
    url.cityName = cityAndzipCode[value].city;
    url.zipCode = cityAndzipCode[value].zipcode;
  } 
}
```

Comment: if (abbrValue) { , what is abbrValue in this, we need to compare the value with stateName in cityAndziCode.json , right

Comment: Corrected it. @Rupam